# how can I retrieve multi sub strings with keeping their order

Tags: c#

I want to read string variable that contains this:

==title1==

text1...

==title2==

text2...

.
.
.
etc

I want to retrieve title1, title2 and etc sub strings, then create separate files like this:

title1.txt contains text1

title2.txt contains text2

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] split = yourString.Split(new string[] { "==" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

That will give you an array with these entrys: title1, text1, title2, text2 etc.
Now when you iterate through the array you will have the title every second loop. So increment by 2 and you will have the title at i and the corresponding text at i+1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i+=2){
     File.WriteAllText("yourPath/" + split[i] + ".txt", split[i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by change code to this:

```
   _edit = edit.InnerText.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
                   // _edit = edit.InnerText.Replace("<lt;ref&", "<ref>");
                   // _edit = edit.InnerText.Replace("&lt;/ref>", "</ref>");
                    string[] split = _edit.Split(new[] { "==" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path + title);
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + title + "\\" + "مقدمه.txt"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(split[0]);
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i < split.Length; i += 2)
                    {

                        //split[i].Replace("=", " ");
                        //File.WriteAllText(path + split[i] + ".txt", split[i + 1]);
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + title + "\\" + split[i] + ".txt"))
                        {
                            // Add some text to the file.
                            sw.WriteLine(split[i + 1]);
                        }
                    }
```